# Netbeans, java y base de datos. Problemas al Insertar

Tags: java, sql

HOla tengo esta parte de código:

```
public void inserir(Assignatura as) throws GestorException  {
        //TODO codificar el metode inserir

    String sentenciaSQL = null;
    PreparedStatement elm = null;

    try{         

        elm = con.prepareStatement(sentenciaSQL);

 // elm = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO assignatura (codi, assignatura, dies");

  sentenciaSQL = "INSERT INTO assignatura VALUES (1, "
          +"'Mates','dilluns')";
  elm.executeUpdate(sentenciaSQL);


  //elm.setObject(1,as);
  //elm.executeUpdate();


    } catch (SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("error!"+ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLsState:"+ ex.getSQLState());
    }finally{
        try {
if(elm!=null && !elm.isClosed()){
elm.close();
}
} catch (SQLException ex) {/*llàstima!*/}
try {
if(con!=null && !con.isClosed()){
con.close();
}
      } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(GestorAssignatura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
    }
```

Estoy probando cosas pero no sé 100% como hacerlo.. el sql es este:

```
CREATE TYPE dades_assignatura as (nom character varying(30), hores integer);


CREATE TABLE Assignatura
(
  codi integer NOT NULL,
  assignatura dades_assignatura,
  dies character varying(9)[],
  CONSTRAINT clauPrimariaAssignatura PRIMARY KEY (codi)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE Assignatura
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

me estoy volviendo loca.. no sé 100% como se hace y tampoco encuentro información :(

Comment: Pero cual es tu problema o error?

Comment: Montse!!! ¿Que estas probando? ¿Que no sabes como se hace? ¿Que información buscas!? :) No te vuelvas loca por favor!!! :(

Comment: Pues necesito insertar nuevas asignaturas y me estoy volviendo loca.. no sé como hacerlo.. :(

Comment: el error no me lo da la consola.. así que no se que hago mal.. :(

Comment: el programa completo esta aquí. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143585/base-de-datos-netbeans . El problema lo tengo en este apartado solo.. por eso he creado un post solo de el.. :(

Comment: ¿Por qué creas un tipo `dades_assignatura`?  ¿Podrías dar un motivo válido? ¿Cómo tratarás la inserción de ese `tipo` en consultas preparadas que es lo que deberías implementar aquí? ¿Por qué en el `CREATE TABLE` no creas cada columna por separado en vez de usar el tipo `dades_assignatura`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que tú insert ingresa en el value 3 datos uno de tipo entero y dos de tipo texto, pero tu base de datos tiene campos de tipo distinto al insert que indicas.

Este es un ejemplo para el insert de tu tabla

`INSERT INTO public.assignatura(codi, assignatura, dies)VALUES (1, '("lulu",1)', '{"lunes"}');`

pero no se si tu ultimo campo deba ser un arreglo

`dies character varying(9)[],`

o solo

`dies character varying(9),`